# Mapping unnamed column in stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I've succesfully imported a stored procedure with an computed unnamed column to a complex object. The generated class automatically named this column as `Column1`.

However, when executing this procedure I get an error telling me that the name of the column cannot be matched.

Given that we don't have access to modify the database, is there a way to hint EF on how to map unnamed columns? (by index, perhaps?)